# XmlBeanFactory can't load properties file as place holder?

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I need to load customer fonts in Jasper report, so I use font extenstion. The problem is that I want to load fonts files from a local machine instead of classpath due to legacy problems. So, I configure as folliwing

File jasperreports_extension.properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory

net.sf.jasperreports.extension.fonts.spring.beans.resource=META-INF/fonts/fonts.xml

#extra properties for font path
font.path=C:/Windows/Fonts
```

And fonts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd">

<beans:bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">    
    <beans:property name="locations" value="classpath:jasperreports_extension.properties">  <!--reads config.properties file-->  
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>  
<beans:bean id="Verdana" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFamily">

    <beans:property name="name" value="Verdana"/>

    <beans:property name="normal" value="file:${font.path}/VERDANA.TTF"/>

    <beans:property name="bold" value="file:${font.path}/VERDANAB.TTF"/>

    <beans:property name="italic" value="file:${font.path}/VERDANAI.TTF"/>

    <beans:property name="boldItalic" value="file:${font.path}/VERDANAZ.TTF"/>

    <beans:property name="pdfEncoding" value="Identity-H"/>

    <beans:property name="pdfEmbedded" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
```

But it seems that XmlBeanFactory (in SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory.java) can't load properties using place hoder or am I miss out something?

Error log:

```
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (4) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'normal' threw exception; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : file:${font.path}/VERDANA.TTF
PropertyAccessException 2: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'bold' threw exception; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : file:${font.path}/VERDANAB.TTF
PropertyAccessException 3: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'italic' threw exception; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : file:${font.path}/VERDANAI.TTF
PropertyAccessException 4: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'boldItalic' threw exception; nested exception is net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error opening input stream from URL : file:${font.path}/VERDANAZ.TTF
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
```

**SOLUTIONS**

Following guidance of Himanshu, I create a subclass of SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory.java as below and use it as the factory class in jasperreports_extension.properties. It works as a charm.

```
public class SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory extends
        net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.SpringExtensionsRegistryFactory {
    protected ListableBeanFactory getBeanFactory(String registryId,
            JRPropertiesMap properties)
    {
        ListableBeanFactory factory = super.getBeanFactory(registryId, properties);
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = (PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)factory.getBean("propertyConfigurer");
        cfg.postProcessBeanFactory((XmlBeanFactory)factory);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the spring documentation,

*A bean factory post-processor is a java class which implements the org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. It is executed manually (in the case of the BeanFactory) or automatically (in the case of the ApplicationContext) to apply changes of some sort to an entire BeanFactory, after it has been constructed. Spring includes a number of pre-existing bean factory post-processors, such as PropertyResourceConfigurer and PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer, both described below, and BeanNameAutoProxyCreator, very useful for wrapping other beans transactionally or with any other kind of proxy, as described later in this manual.*

**One way** To use ApplicationContext in place of XMLBeanFactory.

**Other way** Invoke the post processor something like:

```
XmlBeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("beans.xml"));
// create placeholderconfigurer to bring in some property
// values from a Properties file
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer cfg = factory.getBean("<bean id of the property configurer>")
// now actually do the replacement
cfg.postProcessBeanFactory(factory);
```

Comment: I do as you suggested but it still don't read out properties.